# Função Javascript Error Frame

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Como eu seto um error frame em um TextBox através de uma função javascript?

Comment: O que é um error frame? Uma borda vermelha para indicar que não validou?

Comment: Isso mesmo, é como uma borda para o Textbox onde o usuário poderá visualizar os campos em que estão faltando informações ou estão com informações inválidas.

Comment: E é algo tratado pelo asp (WebForms?). Para colocar uma simples borda em CSS é fácil (`border: 1px solid red`)

Comment: Sim em CSS consegui adicionar, porém a intenção é um contorno de fora do TextBox com um pequeno padding de 1px talvez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abaixo segue um exemplo utilizando javascript para alterar a classe CSS do elemento, após verificada alguma condição de erro. **[Clique aqui para visualizar o exemplo no JSFIDDLE.](http://jsfiddle.net/gfcarv/8M9B7/)**

No exemplo utilizo os eventos `CHANGE` e `BLUR`. O primeiro é disparado quando acontecer alguma mudança no campo e o segundo é disparado sempre que o campo perde o foco.

#### HTML

```
<input id="foo" class="ok" type="text" onchange="verificaCampo()" onblur="verificaCampo()">
</input>
```

#### CSS

```
.ok {
}
.erro {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

#### JAVASCRIPT

```
function verificaCampo() {
    var foo = document.getElementById("foo");

    if (foo.value !== "entendi" ) { // adicione alguma cond de erro
        foo.className = "erro";
    } else {         
        // nao existem erros       
        foo.className = "ok";
    }
}
```

Pode-se também utilizar um tratamento de evento que verifica se os campos estão corretamente preenchidos no momento em que o cliente tentar submeter o formulário. Desta forma o sistema fica mais responsivo, uma vez que não precisa esperar o servidor responder para saber que há algo errado no formulário. Mas **cuidado**, não se esqueça de testar os dados também no servidor pois não existe garantia dos dados que provém do cliente (o javascript pode estar desativado no cliente, por exemplo).